# debugging arrays of lists

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

For code such as this:

```
std::list<int> a[3][3];

int myNumber = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        a[i][j].push_back(myNumber);
        myNumber++;
    }
}
```

The Local window of the debugger shows:

[image]

There is no easy way to go through and see that:

list a[ 0 ][ 0 ] contains 0

list a[ 0 ][ 1 ] contains 1

list a[ 0 ][ 2 ] contains 2

list a[ 1 ][ 0 ] contains 3
etc.

I can only see what lists [ 0 ][ 0 ], [ 1 ][ 0 ], and [ 2 ][ 0 ] contain but I want to see what all the lists contain. How do I go about doing this in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: `list a[ 0 ][ 0 ] contains 0` That's not even true; `a[0][0]` is a `std::list` object, not a number. `a[0][0][0]` (if subscript were available for `list`) is 0. Why do you have an entire list for each single value? Are you sure you didn't mean to have a `std::list<int> a[3]`?

Comment: a[ 0 ][ 0 ] is a list which contains the number 0 correct? The code above is just a simple example, but I have other code which uses 2 different values to determine which list to grab data from, so a 2D array seemed like it would work.

Comment: It's a list which contains _just_ the number 0, which seems completely pointless. And to answer your real question, you can't directly examine standard containers in your debugger so simply as they implement indirection.

Comment: I tried to keep the example simple as not to distract from my question but it appears as though my plan has backfired. But yes, a list with just the number 0 isn't very useful. I would like to examine the contents of the list when I hit a certain breakpoint. The answer below seems very time consuming if the list was large. Is there a better way?

Comment: @user974967: Check my answer. It even shows possible solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"There is no easy way to go through and see that list `a[0][2]` contains 2"*

You right click somewhere into code, chose **Quick Watch**, write there `a[0][2]` and with **Add Watch** you put into **"Watch 1"** so that you can see your `list<int>` at `a[0][2]` properly.

When you declare simple `list<int> l;`, Visual Studio shows it properly. You are able to see all elements.

But when you declare array of lists like this:

```
std::list<int> l[2];
l[1].push_back(3);
l[1].push_back(4);
```

then variable `l` is considered pointer to first `std::list<int>` so even if you push elements into list at index 1, Visual Studio just shows you that `l` is empty list: `some address [0]()`. I can see `l[1]` only if its in Watch:
[image]

Possible solution is to replace simple c-style array (`[]`) with `std::vector` :

```
std::vector<std::list<int> > l;
l.resize(2);

l[1].push_back(3);
l[1].push_back(4);
```

so `l` is not considered a pointer to first `list` anymore. Since `l` is `vector` Visual Studio displays you all elements properly:
[image]

Comment: When does a `std::list` instance have a value "equal to 2"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Right, that was incorrect. I have rewritten it.

Comment: When is a `std::list` a "vector"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I have fixed my answer. Could you remove your downvote? Thanks.

Comment: Can you really examine standard containers in the watch window?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Check it out now.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Yes.  At least you could in VS2008 and VS2003.  Go into the watch window and hit F1.  I *think* the associated file is named autoexp.dat somewhere in the visual studio directory.

Comment: Thanks LihO. The situation is not ideal but I don't think a better solution exists.